# Prevent defatul when click on a tag

Tags: javascript

My client wants a feature that nothing happens when we click on the  tag, but it should behave normally when we ctrl + click on that link (open new tab) or right-click on the link and choose open new tab. Is this possible to do this?

I try `e.preventDetault()` or add `onclick="return false;"` to the link but nothing works

```
<a href="http://google.com/"><img src="..."></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you might want use to **target** attribute on an anchor tag, (you don't need javascript for this)

```
<a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="..."></a>
```

clicking on the link will open it new tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that to happen in click of an anchor tag, below is a demo of how you can do it.. The code will stop the default redirection behavior of the anchor tag and detect if ctrl was pressed when the link was clicked.

Below is a demo using jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.link').on('click', function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    if ($event.ctrlKey && event.which === 1) {
      console.log('Ctrl + click');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923465/"> Go to Goggle</a>
```

Below is a demo using plain javascript

```js
function gotoGoogle(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.which === 1) {
    console.log("inside Ctrl+click");
    console.log(window.location.href)
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stacksnippets.net/" onclick="gotoGoogle(event)">Goto Google</a>
```

**UPDATE:**

Using links to stacksnippets and stackoverflow itself. Everything works as expected. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: but when I right-click on it and choose 'open link in new tab', this does not work

Comment: $(document).on('click', ".link", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
        console.log('CLICK: ', e)
    });

Comment: How can I use Jquery like this? I try but it does not work with Jquery

Comment: @coinhndp update d the answer with both plain javascript and jQuery snippet..

Comment: Ok I found the issue! If I put google to href then it works perfectly. However, when I put the link which has the same domain with my website (internal link), it does not work, the e.preventDefault() cannot prevent the default behaviour

Comment: Could edit the answer and add an internal link (StackOverflow link) to see how it goes?

Comment: @coinhndp did that. and used both the stacksnippet link and stackoverflow. Everything works as expected. May be there something else with your code thats messing up stuff..

Comment: It may work because you have a image inside your anchor tag and stopPropagation stops the event from propagationg.. still it is not the right choice may fail so the right choice is preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onclick = function(event)
{
 if (event.target.nodeName == 'a' && event.which == 1)
 {
  event.preventDefault();
 }
}
```

You can choose literally *which* button, see [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by just add a class with anchore tag and use external script file. please see code below

in html

```
<a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank" id="example"><img src="..."></a>
```

in script.js

```
let example = document.getElementById('example');
example.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: I did this but it does not work since the link has the href